# CSS - Change drop down list/menu so they are same in all browsers

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have some drop down lists on my website, Currently they change their display depending on what browser/os they are being displayed on.

I would like to know how I could change their display so it looks the same on all browsers (preferably how it is displayed using a mac)

Any help would be much appreciated!!

this is my current code

```
<select name="university" id="university" >
          <option value="Aston">Aston University</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: By default, drop down will always inherit native styles. You will have to skin it for cross browser consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, you can use a bit of javascript and css for this.

```
<span class="select"><span>Aston University</span><select><option value="Aston">Aston University</option></select></span>
```

Set position relative on the `.select` and have the actual `<select>` fill up the entire space within by setting it to position absolute and using `top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;`. Set opacity 0 on the `<select>`, de options will still be visible after a click. Use javascript to get the current value from the `<select>` and update the inner span with that value (also listen to change event).

Voila, you can now style your `.select` whichever way you like.